# Curry Currency Converter: no dropdown selection

Tags: curry-currency-converter

The demo in the download linked at the top of the page doesn't display selection dropdown lists (I've tried with FF, IE, Chrome).
Also, when adding the code snippets of the manual page (including references to the javascript and the jQuery files) to a regular webpage, there's also no dropdown list displayed. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you give an online example of what you have tried?
This could be related to the fact that the files are not running on a server.

Comment: damn… indeed, on the server the dropdown box is displayed! How can that be, all references to files look fine to me?!

Comment: curry makes an ajax request to get the currencies from a different domain. This will not work without an legit web address (and as result without a server) due to the browsers CORS policy.

Comment: oh, ic, that explains it. Thanks! It may be worthwhile to add that to the setup instructions, as I'm sure many devs will test on localhost first.